# Calling onSaveEntry event only for one section

Tags: plugin-development

Using the entries.onSaveEntry event, how would I ensure it's only applied to entries in a particular section? Or is there a way to make a distinction between an entry saved from the control panel and an entry created on a front-end form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would compare against the entry's section / entry type in a conditional. The entry modal is available from the event params `$event->params['entry']`.

```
craft()->on('entries.onSaveEntry', function(Event $event)
{
    $entry = $event->params['entry'];

    if($entry->section['handle'] == 'mySection' && $entry->type['handle'] == 'myEntryType')
    {
        // Execute for mySection / myEntryType entries only!
    }
}
```